# rails 3.2: confirm delete. In development confim dialogs opens once, but in production it opens three times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, confirm

I have a rails form that includes some links to delete sub-objects via remote. These links have a confirm option. In development, this works fine. However, in production when I click on the delete link, the confirmation dialogue opens three times. That is, the confirmation dialogue appears, the user clicks on OK and the dialogue appears again. They click OK, and it appears again. Then on the third attempt it goes, and the deletion occurs correctly.

This is the form code:

```
<% delete_link_id = ['delete','notification', @notification.id, 'supporting_document', supporting_document.id, Time.now.to_i].join('_') %>
<%= link_to(
      'Delete',
      notification_supporting_document_path(@notification, supporting_document),
      method: 'delete',
      confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete #{supporting_document.name}?",
      remote: true,
      id: delete_link_id,
      class: 'btn btn-danger'
    )
%>
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $(function() {
    theUnexpected.successRefreshList('#<%= delete_link_id %>');
  });
<% end %>
```

Notifications is the main object, and SupportingDocument is the sub-object being deleted.

This is the JavaScript for theUnexpected.successRefreshList

```
theUnexpected.successRefreshList = function(anchor){
  $(anchor).on('ajax:success',function( event, data, status, xhr ) {
    $('#supporting_documents .list').html(data);
  });
};
```

which on success, replaces the list of supporting documents with the current list. Note that this list includes a new set of deletion links.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why the confirmation dialogue is opening three times in production?

Comment: Make sure confirmation handler Javascript is not loading thrice and if you are using 
`javascript_include_tag` in bottom of the page move it to `<head>` and check.

Comment: My javascript_include_tag is in the header and only once. The are some corporate headers being included, but I've just excluded them and tested again and the problem remains. I've also checked for multiple loads of jquery.js but I cannot see any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. The 'production' environment wasn't actually 'production', it was a custom 'uat' environment. The uat configuration file had been created by copying config/environment/development.rb so that all noisy error messages were still generated in uat, so as to make bug fixing easier. However, the asset pipeline configuration had been left as used in development. The application was being deployed via a standard capistrano deployment script which was compiling the assets.

This meant that all the assets (including the JavaScript files) where being loaded both individually, and via the precompiled asset pipeline. That is, all the JavaScript code was duplicated.

I've modified the config/environment/uat.rb and the confirmation dialogue duplication has gone away:

```
  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and enable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
```